# Getting bash error and no response while using REST API

Tags: visualforce, rest-api

I write a visualforce page with code

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:outputText >{!$Api.Session_ID} </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

i copied the session Id.and used curl and run the command

```
 curl --header "Authorization : Bearer 00D90000000oX2G!AR8AQF4bfKL.F59U3YiDpt3WY5McM6lhzPhoQzTgkpuBUi1gbEMFXlWgCfq4QmufGh.Zw.VlGN4HCCG0S93qlcy671cQ6xcG" https://mydevorg-dev-ed--c.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/
```

and getting error bash:

```
!AR8AQF4bfKL.F59U3YiDpt3WY5McM6lhzPhoQzTgkpuBUi1gbEMFXlWgCfq4QmufGh.Zw.VlGN4HCCG0S93qlcy671cQ6xcG": event not found
```

then I used chrome extension Advanced rest client and send the request

GET https://mydevorg-dev-ed--c.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/

Request Header Authorization: Bearer 00D90000000oX2G!AR8AQF4bfKL.F59U3YiDpt3WY5McM6lhzPhoQzTgkpuBUi1gbEMFXlWgCfq4QmufGh.Zw.VlGN4HCCG0S93qlcy671cQ6xcG

and I am getting no response after one minute. Can somebody tell me why I am unable to call the REST API?

Comment: Uninstall the chrome rest api client and try once it will display the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your curl command is that bash is [attempting to interpret the `!` in the session ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/33905). Use single quotes and all will be well:

```
$ curl --header 'Authorization : Bearer 00D50000000IZ3Z!AQ0AQL_LOTS_MORE_SESSION_ID' https://superpat-developer-edition.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/
{"sobjects":"/services/data/v29.0/sobjects","connect":"/services/data/v29.0/connect","query":"/services/data/v29.0/query","theme":"/services/data/v29.0/theme","queryAll":"/services/data/v29.0/queryAll","tooling":"/services/data/v29.0/tooling","chatter":"/services/data/v29.0/chatter","analytics":"/services/data/v29.0/analytics","recent":"/services/data/v29.0/recent","identity":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ","search":"/services/data/v29.0/search","quickActions":"/services/data/v29.0/quickActions","appMenu":"/services/data/v29.0/appMenu"}
```

Not sure what the problem is with the Chrome REST client.